# Is there a mobile friendly text entry markup (akin to Markdown)?

Tags: mobile, markup, mobile-text-entry

Is there a mobile-first markup language?

In my Android phone, typing

```
.h2 hydrogen peroxide
H2O2 or hydrogen peroxide is
```

is easier than

```
## hydrogen peroxide
H2O2 or hydrogen peroxide is
```

In the first case, periods and letters (.h2 or .hh) are easier to access while hash needs two keystrokes per character. Is there such a mobile-first markup language at present?

Comment: Why don't you change the keyboard layout to include `#`?

Comment: iPhone 5 iOS 7 does not include the '.' (period) character on the main keyboard. Nevertheless, I have never heard of mobile friendly markup. There certainly is a place for it (otherwise, we would not be using l33t speak).

Comment: Certainly not MediaWiki code !

Comment: Just to clarify, you're specifically asking about text input formatting markup, correct? (Vs. HTML or the like)

Comment: @DA01 yes. Like Markdown, it must map to HTML

Answer (score 1):

[Touchqode](http://www.touchqode.com/) have released an app in Goolge Play and are planning for a release in App Store. The app makes it easier to do real editing in real languages with the following features:

> - syntax highlighting
> - code suggestions
> - incremental search

... to mention a few things.

It's the opposite direction of what you're suggesting. But I think it's better to use excisting programming/markup languages, instead of inventing new ones.